# How to write list of lists to CSV file Python?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list of lists like `[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'),....]`. I want to write it to a CSV file like this-

```
a,   b,   c
d,   e,   f
```

How do I do that?

I've tried using csv.writerows but the output file had each character in different cells and all together in same row. In the sense, the cells in row one had '   a   '   '   b   ' etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: If I understand your last part right, do you want `a b c, d e f,`?

Comment: could you write `for lst in wholeList: csv.writerow(lst)`? This yould write every row in another line of the file (or at least i think so).

Comment: Why are you using `writerow` and not `writerows`?

Comment: That is a list of tuples not a list of lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Pandas, it's pretty easy and fast. I assume you have a list of tuples called "data".

```
import pandas as pd
data = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

done!

EDIT: "list of lists" -> "list of tuples"

Comment: Perfect! Thank you and everyone very much for responding.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`writer.writerows()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) (plural, with `s`) to write a list of rows in one go:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import sys
>>> data = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]
>>> writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
>>> writer.writerows(data)
a,b,c
d,e,f
```